# Is there a way to redirect tsc output to one directory if the input has a few?

Tags: typescript, tsc

It's not a huge problem but i just wonder if there's a way to redirect tsc compile output to one directory.

The structure:

```
--src
   --test1.ts
   --subdirectory
      --test2.ts
--dist
--tsconfig.json
--package.json
```

The tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {

"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
  }
}
```

The output:

```
--dist
   --test.js
   --subdirectory
      --test2.js
```

Aaand here's the output i wish i had:

```
--dist
   --test.js
   --test2.js
```

Maybe someone know how to set tsconfig to compile files like that?